# Powershell to .vbs

Tags: powershell, vbscript, range, ip, subnet

Hi can I turn the following onto a .vbs file so when selected it can display the IPAddress in a window e.g Wscript.echo?

```
get-netipaddress | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.AddressFamily -match "IPv4"} |Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.InterfaceAlias -notlike "Loopback*"}| Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -like "192.168*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```

Recommended fix does not work and want to avoid using a .ps1 through a .vbs

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options...

Option 1: VBScript only

The example below assumes that the only filter you really need is "192.168*", as the other filters don't appear to make any difference in my testing. However, YMMV, so you may have to tweak this script:

```
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set oItems = oWMI.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled=TRUE")
 
For Each oItem in oItems
  IP = oItem.IPAddress(0)
  If Left(IP,7) = "192.168" Then IPList = IPList & IP & VBCRLF
Next

MsgBox IPList
```

Option 2: Two script files (.vbs and .ps1)

The example below uses a temp file to pass data between the scripts. This uses all of your original filters, but is very slow compared to the VBScript only version.

IPList.vbs

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oWSH.Run "Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\IPList.ps1",0,True
Temp  = oWSH.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(Temp & "\IPList.txt",1)
IPList = oFile.ReadAll
oFile.Close
MsgBox IPList
```

IPList.ps1

```
get-netipaddress | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.AddressFamily -match "IPv4"} |Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.InterfaceAlias -notlike "Loopback*"}| Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -like "192.168*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress | Out-File -Encoding ascii "$env:TEMP\IPList.txt"
```

Comment: .vbs works a treat thanks so much!!